# reducing FP rate scikit-learn random forest

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am working with the scikit-learn random forest classifier and I want to reduce the FP rate by increasing the number of trees needed for a successful vote from greater than 50% to say 75%, after reading the documentation I am not sure of how to do this. Does anyone have any suggestions. (I think there should be a way to do this because according to the documentation the predict method of the classifier decides based on a majority vote). All help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `predict_proba() >= 0.75`?

Comment: @hiqbal dont forget to accept my answer in case it suits you... :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you now have a classifier that use as 75% agreement within all the estimators. In case it gets a new sample, and the odds are 51%-49% in favour of one class, what do you want it to do?

The reason that 50% rule is used, is because a decision rule as you proposed may lead you to cases where the classifier says "I cannot predict the label of these samples".

What you *can* do, is to wrap the results of the classifier, and do whatever calculations you wish -

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np

def my_decision_function(arr):
    diff = np.abs(arr[:,0]-arr[:,1])
    arr [ diff < 0.5 ] = [-1,-1] # if >0.5, one class has more than 0.75 prediction
    return arr


X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=100000, n_features=20,
                                n_informative=2, n_redundant=2)
train_samples = 100  # Samples used for training the models

X_train = X[:train_samples]
X_test = X[train_samples:]
y_train = y[:train_samples]
y_test = y[train_samples:]

clf = RandomForestClassifier().fit(X_train,y_train)
print my_decision_function(clf.predict_proba(X_train))
```

Now, each sample with less than 0.75% for at least one class will have `[-1,-1]` prediction. Some adjustments most be made if you use do multi-label classification, but I hope the notion is clear.